# Why do we use && and || while "and" and "or" also work?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I always use "and" and "or", but at college I learned that we should use && and ||...

Comment: I have had instances where `and` and `or` were not recognized by the compiler.  However, `&&` and `||` have **always** been recognized by the compilers (especially when you have old code that must be compiled with old compilers).

Comment: Not all compilers support `and` and `or` correctly. Personally I regard such code as idiosyncratic, but that might fall away with the advent of Python. I also find that `or` doesn't really distinguish `||` and `|` adequately?

Comment: Searching for `&&` and `||` gives a lot fewer false positives.

Comment: There is no difference between them. It's customary to use `&&` `||` though, so I recommend you to get used to it.

Comment: @Bathsheba neither AND, btw - all those symbolic names fail to convey the nature of the operation - whether it is bit-wise or logical. I tend to think of them as bad influence (I doubt there are really people nowadays who are using symbol pages which do not support special symbols).

Comment: Everyone knows `&&`, all compilers understand it, it's shorter than `and`. Other alternative tokens like `not_eq` are clumsy - you would end up mixing styles inconsistently.

Answer (score 3):

This related to character encoding, the source code maybe not written in any non-ASCII 7-bit character (ex: [ISO 646:1983](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_646)) and serving compatibility to code that use this operator.

Reference:

- [Alternative Operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative)

Comment: I like this answer. While it does not directly answers the question "why", it empowers the reader to make their own projections.

Comment: If your source character set doesn't have `&`, all your references and pointers are in for a world of hurt.

Comment: @BenVoigt why? `bitend` would work.

Comment: @SergeyA: You mean `bitand`?  But while it may make the lexer happy, it's semantically incorrect and going to cause mental anguish for anyone working with the code.

Comment: @BenVoigt sure, `bitand`. I am not saying it is a welcome practice to write code in such a manner, I am just saying that references and pointers would survive.

Comment: @BenVoigt `#define ref bitand` and then `int ref i = a;` (I am just joking)